# Why do I get an conversion error in android using R.string?

Tags: android

My file `strings.xml` looks like the following:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">BootIntervals</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="logname">"bi2.log"</string>
</resources>
```

and later I call a method

```
 logger.init(R.string.logname);
```

which takes a `String` as argument. However, I get the following error:

```
Error:(21, 15) error: method init in class MyLogger cannot be applied to given types;
required: String
found: int
reason: actual argument int cannot be converted to String by method invocation conversion
```

It does not matter if I use `bi2.log` or `"bi2.log"` in `strings.xml`. What do I make wrong this time? I do not understand why `R.string.logname` is an integer...

Comment: I have very little Android knowlegde, but isn't `R.string.logname` an id that you need to use to find the string with?

Comment: Maybe you are right...

Comment: I have even less Android knowledge.

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
this.getResources().getString(R.string.logname)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use

```
getString(yourResourceId);
```

In your case, something like this

```
logger.init(getString(R.string.logname));
```